# Android compilation: what differences can make code compile on one computer but fail on another

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have project in Ionic, which I'm trying to compile with `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` - **it's the exact same code** (pulled from the same remote repository, same commit, clean location).

The problem is: on one computer the command produces an `.apk` file, as expected.
On another computer the command fails (at the end of the question I'll post the errors).

Android Studio is almost the same version (there's a small difference in the minor), and in the preferences all the settings in SDK Platforms, SDK Tools and SDK Update Sites are exactly the same.

All other relevant software has the exact same version.

```
C:\Users\my_user>ionic -version
3.19.0

C:\Users\my_user>java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"

C:\Users\my_user>gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-12-06 09:05:06 UTC
Revision:     cf7821a6f79f8e2a598df21780e3ff7ce8db2b82

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_151 (Oracle Corporation 25.151-b12)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

What can be different between the computers that I should check?
Maybe some environment variables? Which ones?

The compilation error is:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/PermissionHelper;
```

I then fixed this problem by adding `multiDexEnabled true` in the `defaultConfig` section in the `platforms\android\build.gradle` file, and got another error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/cordova/PermissionHelper.class
```

What can be different between the computers that I should check?
Maybe some environment variables? Which ones?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Posting in case it helps someone.

The problem was a different cordova version (get it with `cordova -version`).
One computer had 7.0.1 (and could **not** create an .apk).
The other computer had 7.1.0 (and **could** create an .apk).